# Show that $\angle ADH = \frac{\pi}4$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, homothety

$DB$ is a diameter of the bigger circle whose center is $A$.

$I$ and $C$ are the midpoints of the circular arcs $\widehat{DB}$

Point $E$ is a random point in line $DB$ and $F$ is the contact point between the bigger and smaller circle, the latter being also tangent to $DB$ on $E$.

Point $H$ is the meeting of $FB$ and the perpendicular to $DB$ through $E$.

Show that $D,H$ and $I$ are always collinear (as $E$ moves through $DB$)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $M$ be center of the other circle. $|FM|=|ME|$ and $|FA|=|AC|$ and so, $FME \sim FAC$. Hence, $F, E, C$ are collinear. Since $C$ is mid-point of the arc $BD$, $\angle DFC = \angle BFC = 45^\circ$. $DEHF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $\angle EDH = \angle EFH = \angle CFB = 45^\circ$ and we are done!

Comment: Shouldn't the first equality be FM = ME instead?

Comment: Thank you @Mick . I corrected my typo